# Do I add my functions for a module into a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on a function library/module for a project. I was wondering, to use it in another file as a module, do I need to put it in a class? I've tried adding my module to other files, but it doesn't work. Also, a lot of other built-in modules are in a class. Should I put it in a class or not? I'm also looking for an objective answer and not if it's a common practice or not.

Comment: Hello there! Which error that is being shown? Care to give us more details?

Comment: Objective answer: it depends. There is no _need_ to wrap functions in a class inside a module. You've just had issues with importing the functions but you've not shown what those issues are

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Provide some code samples: how do you declare your functions/classes in one module and how do you use it in another one?

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832). BTW, check [ask] if you want advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put it in a class or let it outside a class. It depends on the use of this function.

e.g.:

```py
class MyClass:
    
    @staticmethod
    def function(arguments):
        # Your code
```

In order to import it you will have to use this:
`from name_of_the_file import name_of_the_class`

In the file you will have to use `name_of_the_class.name_of_the_function()`.

e.g.:

```py
MyClass.function(arguments)
```

If you define the function outside a class:
`from name_of_the_file import name_of_the_function`

Comment: That would have to be a `staticmethod` and they generally aren't used all that often

Comment: Thanks I added the @classmethod decorator, You are right I usually use classmehtod and not static

Comment: The decorator needs to be `staticmethod` not `classmethod`. The wrapping of functions in a class (for no good reason) is not a reason to want to return an instance of the class

Comment: ok edited then. The question is unclear anyways

Answer (score 0):

In general, you don't need to put functions in a class. For example, [`functools.wraps()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) is a function.

However, you haven't mentioned the actual problem you're having, so this general answer is probably not very helpful.